# Make a sticky header with CSS position fixed

Tags: css, header, fixed, sticky

I need to make a sticky header. We did a sticky footer in computerclass with CSS postion: fixed and it worked great. But I cannot transpose the code for the sticky footer to a sticky header. Position fixed works, but the article scrolls underneath of the header – which is of course not beautiful.
When I apply CSS code I find on Stackoverflow, the image of the header moves tot he left corner down of the screen. This is code on stackoverflow:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 3.5em;
padding:0;
margin: 0;
```

I have a header, some whitespace, an article and an aside. Here is the CSS code of the header that I use and scrolls underneath the article:

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    color: #5B493D;
}

header {
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
#whitespace {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}
article {
    width: 70%;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

And this is what we did in class for a sticky footer which worked well:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="nav">
            <a href="#">Home</a> <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">News</a> <a href="#">Special Offers</a>
            <a href="#">Content</a> <a href="#">Links</a>
            <a href="#">Extra link</a>
        </div>
        <div id="article"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="whitespace"></div>
    <div id="sticky"></div>
</body>
```

And some of the CSS:

```
#article {
    background-color: #6CC;
    height: 500px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #399;
    height: 90px;
}
#sticky {
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(../images/bottom.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-position: center center;
}
#whitespace {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Someone who knows how to ‘merge’ footer and header so that the header works, and without the image of the header moving down left to the screen? (I do not need a sticky footer, only a sticky header).
To make it even more difficult: this website has to be responsive.

Comment: And we are supposed to figure it out with no HTML?

Comment: please provide HTML or at least a link to the page

Comment: The HTML you posted does not have any div with id=whitespace..

Comment: if sticky header has a known height, then use this value as a padding-top for the wrapper, so content in the flow it starts underneath the header at the padding-top valu you set

Comment: Not sure if it is a good idea of if i'm going to confuse you, but you could consider display:flex and position:sticky. If you are learning now, by the time you 'll become handy, flex and sticky will be commonly used . take a look at  http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/RaaGWq?editors=1100 (i reduced height of header/footer and added aside missiing :) . about the position:sticky: http://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/

Comment: Uhm.... Kinda confused with what your problem is. A "sticky" header will remain at the top as you scroll, so the content will kinda have to scroll underneath it. Just slap a `box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 black;` or similar on it and it'll _look_ better....

Answer (score 0):

If you set the position to fix, the element gets removed from the css flow, so it's normal that the article scrolls underneath the header. A quick workaround would be to simply set a background to your header.

If I misunderstood your question, can you include a jsfiddle/codepen link to it's easier to understand?

Comment: he says that he has used a #whitespace that is supposed to fill in for the header..

Comment: his whitespace is only 100px wide so of course he will see content underneath. A simpler solution would still be to just add a background color to his header.

Comment: The width does not matter if the height of #whitespace is equal to the height of the header it should work, the OP probably has the CSS for the whitespace but not the actual div

Comment: You are right@user1991072, this works. I have a problem however: the wrapper has a fluid background color, the header only has an image. When I try to make only the image background, and the image is not very big, the article keeps scrolling underneath the header.

Comment: As long as you are using position:fixed, there will be content that scrolls underneath the element, that's how position:fixed works, you just have to be creative and find a way to hide the content underneath ;)

As mentioned above, please provide a jsfiddle link so we can help you more.

Comment: @Fanckush I have this in the HTML    <header> <img class = "logo" src="img/octlogowit.jpg" width="530" height="81" alt="logo octogoon"></header>
<div id = "whitespace"></div>
<div class="wrapper">

Comment: For the jsfiddle, I'm afraid I'm a beginner at js and jquery, I'm following a computerclass but had never even heard this word! So I'll have to ask my teacher next lesson how to make a jsfiddle for stackoverflow purposes. Sorry.

Comment: No worries ;) Go on this website, https://jsfiddle.net/, put your html in the html section, and your css in the CSS section, then click Save and paste the url in a comment below.

Comment: Thx to all of you. And @Xposedbones for learning me about jsfiddle. I have computer class tomorrow, will see what comes out of it, wil let you know. Else, I'll create a jsfiddle. Wow.